# html img tag not showing image on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, image

https://solankivj.netlify.com

images are not showing on mobile browsers in MY PROJECT section.
Its showing all images perfectly on PC browsers.

Comment: It's showing up in my phone, a little distorted, but it's showing. _Maybe_ your phone can't handle `grid` very well. You can check [`@supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports)

Comment: share your code if you wanna be helped.